# force the creation of an intermediate table `Blog_Post`

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, entity-framework-core, ef-core-5.0

Is there a way (ef-core-5.0) to force the creation of an intermediate table `Blog_Post` for the following code?

```
Blog <= 0,n => Blog_Post <= 1,1 => Post
```

the code is the following

```
class MyContext : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<Blog> Blogs { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Post> Posts { get; set; }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {

    }
}

public class Blog
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Url { get; set; }
}

public class Post
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public string Content { get; set; }
}
```

From one side, I want to separate concerns, and not add too much DB stuff on the business classes. So I would prefer do not use as much as possible an explicit DB configuration, attributes, ad-hoc table classes etc, or probably better a Fluent configuration...

From another, there's no many to many relation between Blog and Post.

However, such link tables are necessary to be built for a specific reason in the DB.

Comment: Are you talking about a many-to-many relationship?

Comment: @insane_developer, one, or many, is does not really matter, actually, *I just want to create an intermediary table*. Actually a Blog can have zero or multiple Posts. but anyway, a table Blog_Post should be created.

Comment: You can do that but it requires navigation properties in your classes. I know there are examples for many-to-many relationships where you can specify the join table's name and even add more fields to it. You can try that approach for a one-to-many relationship, like it's the case with Blog and Post. However, if you want to manage the table yourself, just create another entity for it and update it yourself.

Answer (score -1):

With EFCore 5 if you declare the relationship between A - B as `.HasMany` `.WithMany` EF will create the joining table automatically. If you just want to control the creation/naming of the joining you can use `.UsingEntity` after `.WithMany` to define an entity to outline the join. Note that Entity A can still contain an `ICollection<B>` while B contains an `ICollection<A>` respectively, not A_B.  See: https://dev.to/ruben_j/many-to-many-relations-in-entity-framework-core-3-1-and-5-59ei  About 1/2 way through he covers off EF Core 5 including `UsingEntity`.

If you do want more control and to expose A_B so that you can have additional properties, then the relationship between A - B needs to be updated to use A_B to form effectively a one-to-many-to-one form of navigation:

```
public class A
{
    [Key]
    public int AId { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<AB> ABs { get; internal set; } = new List<AB>();
}

public class B
{
    [Key]
    public int BId { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<AB> ABs { get; internal set; } = new List<AB>();
}

[Table("A_B")]
public class AB
{
    [Key, Column(Order=0), ForeignKey("A")]
    public int AId { get; set; }
    [Key, Column(Order=1), ForeignKey("B")]
    public int BId { get; set; }

    public virtual A { get; set; }
    public virtual B { get; set; }
}
```

This approach allows you to associate additional columns into AB such as tracking CreatedAt/By ModifiedAt/By for when associations are created/updated, or other properties. This doesn't require `UsingEntity` when done this way.  This is more in line with how to create many-to-many relationships in EFCore prior to EF Core 5.

Comment: From one side, I want to separate concerns, and not add too much DB stuff on the business classes. From another, there's no many to many relation between Blog and Post. However, such link tables are necessary to be built for a specific reason in the DB.